# How to change form title when you change form language?

Tags: vb.net, localization

I have a vb.net WinForms app and one form (frmUser) in the app is used to set user settings, including the UI language via ComboBox. When I change the language with the ComboBox using the following code, text of all controls in frmUser are changed correctly, except for the Form title! The form title is from the second language in the ComboBox, regardles of selection.

```vb
Call ChangeLanguage(frmUser, cboxLang.SelectedItem)
```

```vb
Private Sub ChangeLanguage(ByRef frm As Form, ByVal Language As String)
    Dim crmLang As ComponentResourceManager = New ComponentResourceManager(frm.GetType)

    For Each c As Control In frm.Controls
        crmLang.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, New CultureInfo(Language))
    Next c
End Sub
```

Of course, I can set `frmUser.Text` via code (`Select Case Language ... End Select`), but I'm sure there is a better way to do it. BTW, form titles are known at design time!

Note: I need to change only the language (not the CurrentCulture) so number, date and other formats are determined by the OS.

Comment: The form is a control too so I would think that you could pass it to that `ApplyResources` method as well.

Comment: By the way, why is that `frm` parameter declared `ByRef`? You're not assigning anything to it inside the method so there can't be any good reason for it. Change it to `ByVal`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney `crmLang.ApplyResources(frm, frm.Name, New CultureInfo(Language))` doesn't work, or I'm missing something?

Comment: @jmcilhinney it doesn't matter, `ByRef` or `ByVal`! The idea was to have a single public sub for other forms. If it is just for `frmUser`, it could be omitted and reference the form by `Me`

Comment: It doesn't matter if you don't mind writing bad code. If you want to write good code then use `ByVal` in all cases except where you specifically need to pass by reference, which you don't in this case.

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is never an adequate explanation. I've never really done anything with multiple languages or cultures so that was a bit of a guess. Presumably you would actually have to have dedicated resources for a particular language and control property for anything to happen when you call `ApplyResources` and pass a particular language and control. Do you have a resource in that language for the `Text` property of that form? If so then I would guess that it would work, but it's only a guess.

Comment: You can iterate the OpenForms collection and set:  `crmLang.ApplyResources([Form], "$this", New CultureInfo(Language))`. Or use the current form: `crmLang.ApplyResources(Me, "$this", New CultureInfo(Language))` if it' the only one you need to change.

Comment: @jmcilhinney **doesn't matter ByRef/ByVal** as stated by MS ([link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/passing-arguments-by-value-and-by-reference `For reference types, only the pointer to the data is copied (four bytes on 32-bit platforms, eight bytes on 64-bit platforms). Therefore, you can pass arguments of type String or Object by value without harming performance.`

Comment: @jmcilhinney on the "doesn't work" comment you're were right. I had all the resource files for every language and all `.Text` fields were translated (in the Design tab), however my VS2017 didn't (and sometimes it doesn't always) propagate the changes made in the Design tab in corresponding `<lang>.resx` files?! After I reconstructed the form, it worked OK! I'm not sure if it's a VS bug or I'm doing something wrong? It appears that it happens if you change the `.Localizable` property of the form when the form is displayed in a language other than the default, VS messes up the `lang.resx` files

Comment: @Jimi your suggestion helped me a lot. My intention is (at a later point) to iterate in to other OpenForms and set `crmLang.ApplyResources`. Now, my problem is solved, however I don't understand why `crmLang.ApplyResources(Me, Me.Name, New CultureInfo(Language))` doesn't work, while yours suggestion `crmLang.ApplyResources(Me, "$this", New CultureInfo(Language))` works? I don't understand `"$this"`? `..c, c.Name..` works for the controls in the form, but `...Me, Me.Name...` doesn't work for the form itself?!

Comment: @jmcilhinney your are right, the quote was not appropriate, but the comment _"doesn't matter"_ still holds in the case for that particular sub: **it doesn't change the variable**! In other situations it "_matters a lot_" and passing mechanism should be chosen appropriately.

Comment: `$this` references the Component itself (the Form Container, here) This is the standard prefix assigned to resource that belong to a Form. You can see it in any resource (`.resx`) file when a resource (the Form's Icon, for example) is stored there. Have you ever used something like: `dim text as string = [ComponentResourceManager].GetString("$this.Text")`?

Comment: @Jimi thank for the clarification. It is the first time I'm accessing a resource from code. I assumed that `$this` has similar meaning as in JavaScript, PHP, etc. but I cannot understand why `control.Name` works for controls in a form, but not for the control itself when the method `.ApplyResources` expects the second argument to be objectName? BTW, I suppose your `dim text ...` example is a mixture of C# and VB.NET, since it doesn't work in VB.NET?!

Comment: I just explained why you use `$this`. Have you looked inside a `.resx` file? You'll see that all fields properties are prefixed by the name of the field, while the Container properties are prefixed by `$this` (e.g., quite common, `$this.Icon`). -- What do you mean *it doesn't work in VB.NET*? You just write: `Dim resources = New ComponentResourceManager(Me.GetType())` then `Dim frmText As String = resources.GetString("$this.Text")` or `Dim frmIcon = resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")`

Comment: @Jimi thank again for the explanation. Now I'm getting somewhere! Actually, the _... Container properties are prefixed by `$this` ..._ part of your comment explained the lot. And the example works, I missed the `Dim resources ...` part!

Answer (score -1):

Learn about localization of Windows Forms applications on MSDN. In short, you set your forms localizable, then set language of that forms and write text in that language. Then switch to another language and write that text again in other language. These texts will be automatically saved to resources and loaded based on thread's UICulture.